# How to do indexing in python dictionary using html template

Tags: python, html, django

```
def send_template(request):
     my_folders = Folders.objects.filter(parent=None).order_by('name')
     new_headers = {}
     for foldr in my_folders:   
          en_count = FolderEntries.objects.filter(folder = foldr.id ).count()        
          new_headers[foldr.id] = en_count
     return render(request, 'folders.html', 'new_headers':new_headers)
```

new_headers contains data in such way:-
{190: 1, 196: 0, 199: 0, 121: 0, 185: 1, 194: 1, 108: 3, 168: 4, 197: 0, 195: 0, 198: 0, 171: 1}

Now i want to get new_headers in html template using indexing
For example:-
new_headers[190]

*How to do this..Anyone plz help*

i am sending this data to my html template:-
{190: 1, 196: 0, 199: 0, 121: 0, 185: 1, 194: 1, 108: 3, 168: 4, 197: 0, 195: 0, 198: 0, 171: 1}

Now i want to do indexing in this data.

Comment: Indexing is deliberately not supported in the Django template language, because it is writing business logic in the template. For a fixed key, you can use `new_headers.190`, you can also register a custom lookup, but usually that means that the logic is not effective.

Comment: I think this is not possible to run this loop dynamically like:-                                                                                     {{new_headers.folder.id}}                                                    I want to pass dynamic values in place of 190

Comment: no indeed, you can not use an arbitrary variable since that would introduce business logic in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is deliberately not supported in the Django template language, because it is writing business logic in the template. For a fixed key, you can use `new_headers.190`, you can also register a custom lookup, but usually that means that the logic is not effective.

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count


def send_template(request):
    my_folders = (
        Folders.objects.filter(parent=None)
        .order_by('name')
        .annotate(num_entries=Count('folderentries'))
    )
    return render(request, 'folders.html', {'new_headers': new_headers})
```

The `Folders` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.num_entries`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without modifying my django tables structures

Comment: @erabhi: no table structure is modified. This simple makes a *query* that will add the count for each `Folder`. By using annotate, you also do this in *one* query, and thus omit an *N+1 problem*.

Comment: okk...i got your point....But let me clear one concept.....the extra field that i am adding to my queryset is filtered from dictionary....let us suppose i have a dictionary {1: 3, 10: 2, 4: 9} now if folder id is 1 in my loop then append value 3 to my query set same for other folders as well.....how can i make query for this.....Little more help will be very appreciable

Comment: In my case i am not combining new value to my each queryset objects using existing values of queryset object ..........As much infomation i have got "annotate has a different purpose. It annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of query expressions. An expression may be a simple value, a reference to a field on the model (or any related models), or an aggregate expression (averages, sums, etc.) that has been computed over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet."